# How to write current date in ASP Code?

Tags: asp-classic

May i know how to write a ASP code to show current date ? For the example, if user key in today date, the system will allow, while if the user key in previous date it will block and show error message. thank you.

As below is the ASP code

```
DIM PINVDATE,PTQTY

PINVDATE = Request.Form("PINVDATE")
PTQTY = Request.Form("PTQTY")

If TRIM(PINVDATE) = "" and TRIM(PTQTY) = "" Then

Msg = "** Mandatory Field not filled, please check !!!"

Response.Redirect "plan.asp?empid="& EmpID & "&Name=" & EmpName & "&EmpLevel=" & EmpLevel & "&ref=" & Msg

else

If TRIM(PINVDATE) = "" THEN

Msg = "** Date not filled, Please Check !!!"

Response.Redirect "plan.asp?empid="& EmpID & "&Name=" & EmpName & "&EmpLevel=" & EmpLevel & "&ref=" & Msg

else

if TRIM(PTQTY) = "" then

Msg = "** Quantity not filled, Please Check !!!"

Response.Redirect "plan.asp?empid="& EmpID & "&Name=" & EmpName & "&EmpLevel=" & EmpLevel & "&ref=" & Msg

END IF
END IF
END IF

<tr>
<th bgcolor="#8585A6" ><font color="white">Date</font></th>
<th colspan = 3 bgcolor="#ECE5B6" align=left><input type ="text" name="PINVDATE" style="text-align: left" size = 23 maxlength="30"/><font color='Red'>** Exp: YYYY-MM-DD</font></th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Date function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_date.asp) and [Datediff function](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_datediff.asp)

```
if DateDiff("d",Date(),CDate(TRIM(PINVDATE))) <> 0 Then
'show Error
```

Comment: HI, thank you for reply, i using MS SQL database, the table i created in date format is  YYYY-MM-DD. is it i need to edit like this if DateDiff("YYYY-MM-DD",Date(),CDate(TRIM(PINVDATE))) <> 0 Then
'show Error message, kindly advise. thank  you

Comment: please check the link for datediff function in my post."d" is not for the format of the date.

Comment: @caulson the `Date()` and `Now()` functions return the current date on the server. They both use the Regional Settings as configured on the server, if it's "YYYY-MM-DD" then this code will work otherwise either change the settings on the server (via Control Panel --> Date/Time Settings) or parse the given date yourself and build two dates from scratch. Not going to be simple, but if you can't change Regional Settings and can't rely on them being consistent, that's the only way that will surely work.